# Voltage sag during standby generator switching

Tags: voltage, generator

A hospital has a 1.5 MVA standby 400/230-volt generator.

The generator produces a severe sag that causes equipment to fail partially, the repeated switching could lead to memory corruption and some have to be reprogrammed like respiratory equipment and since there are several pieces of equipment (> 2900 equipment) it causes great concern.

This voltage dip occurs only in the switch-over between the grid supply and the generator supply.

During the steady-state operation, the generator runs smoothly with no problems.

Since the on-load test is done monthly, this problem occurs twice for every on-load test.

I contacted a manufacturer for advice on shunt capacitors, he advised me that they provide limited protection to impulses, not generator starting sag which lasts several cycles.

A manufacturer recommended a make before break change-over switch, however, this won't solve the problem of real outages which can happen on a weekend with very few staff.

What do you think is a good solution for this problem.

Comment: High power Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS) systems exist that could help bridge that gap. Covering the entire facility with one would be a fairly significant project. Less expensive UPSs could be selectively deployed to cover critical systems, but for a hospital going for a facility wide solution might be best.

Comment: If you add a suitable, perhaps quite a bit smaller in capacity, double conversion UPS to the generator and wire the hospital plug receptacles so there is a limited number of plugs per room or per section that are tied directly back to panel for the double conversion UPS system, then only critical equipment would be allowed to use those plugs and everything else is on the regular power panels which may also be fed by the generator. But you should not be getting advice here for this. For that size, you should and can afford to hire a good quality professional in the area.

Comment: I’m in no way an expert and qualified in the field, but some hospitals run diesel backup generator in sync with the grid with special valve train to not pump any air until a grid failure is detected, at which point the valves resumed normal operation and fuel is supplied. This scheme to address the very thing you highlight. Don’t know if it’s common or even relevant these days.

Comment: If the on-load test is done in this way: the unsynchronized generator is connect parallel to the grid and after some milliseconds the connection to the grid is switched of, than a severe sag is to be expected. The generator needs to transit from zero load to nearly full load in a short time. So you should organize a measurement of the synchronization of the generator to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what equipment you have available, but a sync-check relay (like [this one](https://www.basler.com/Product/BE1-25-Sync-Check-Relay)) would only allow the generator breaker to be closed when the voltage magnitudes and phase positions on both sides of the open breaker are within narrow windows.

Get somebody that knows what they’re doing to set it.

By adding more complexity you can use a synchronizer.  It does the sync-check function too but has the added ability to control the generator speed and field (and hence terminal voltage) so it actively brings the machine online smoothly ([here is](https://selinc.com/solutions/Generator-and-Microgrid-Synchronizing-Systems/) example).

In your case I expect you just need the sync-check relay as the on-load test (paralleling) is done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Critical equipment needs to be on a UPS, otherwise there is no way to maintain stable power when switching to generator after a power outage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an 'uninterruptible' battery-backed power supply (UPS) to cover generator starting during a real outage? If not, then your monthly testing should include this bad switchover behaviour, as it's what you need to work with during a genuine outage.

Usually, a backup system that cannot tolerate an interruption sag will have batteries and an inverter that take over when the main power supply fails, and provide power for a few minutes while the generators are started and come up to speed.  Unless the generator is running 24/7, a genuine outage will involved a period of many seconds to a few minutes while the generator is started. Of course, if batteries have to handle 1.5 MVA, that's a sizable battery/inverter installation.

Perhaps a cheaper solution is to identify the items of equipment that *must* receive a clean power supply, and provide each of those locally with a small UPS.